# find highest number in MS access database using C#

Tags: c#, ms-access

How to find the largest number in a particular column of MS access table? I'm using C#.

I'm not able to make the logic for this. I was doing this:

```
int i, lastID;
int y = 0;
int lastRow = DS.Tables[0].Rows.Count;
for (i = 0; i > -1; i++)
{
    i = Convert.ToInt32(DS.Tables[0].Rows[i]["id"].ToString());
    lastID = (y > i) ? y : i;
    if (i > lastRow)
    {
        lastID++;
        empIdLabel.Text = lastID.ToString();
    }
}
```

I'm fussed !!!!

Comment: Is there a reason you can't `select max(id) from . . . `?

Comment: To be honet I was not aware of this command, was trying to use select * from tablemane...... any link to help me learn more about these commands?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Barring an obvious reason why not, you should use SQL: `SELECT MAX(id) FROM . . .`.

You can do this with an OLEDB connection:

```
OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;data source=blahblah.mdb"));
connection.Open();
OleDbCommand maxCommand = new OleDbCommand("SELECT max(id) from TABLENAME", connection);
Int32 max = (Int32)maxCommand.ExecuteScalar();
```

Note that I'm on a Linux machine, so I haven't tested the above, but it should be pretty close from what I remember of C#.

Comment: My sincere appologies, I forgot to mention that I'm using MS Access database Oledb connection type. I can't simply type >>>empIdLabel.Text = select max(id) from emp<<< I'm just trying to fetch the Max value in the column of my database (mdb)

Comment: @gsvirdi - I've edited to show how to do it with an OLEDB connection.

Comment: @gsvirdi - also note that I probably wouldn't just inline the SQL like I did above in my illustration.

Comment: Thx **JasonFruit** for ur help. I was able to figureout the code 
        OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(conString);
        var empcon = new OleDbCommand("SELECT max(id) FROM [emp]", con);
        try
        {
            con.Open();
            Int32 max = (Int32)empcon.ExecuteScalar();
            empIdLabel.Text = (max + 1).ToString();
        }

Comment: @gsvirdi - Sounds like you got it.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

you can use SQL for this purpose

```
select max(id) from tablename
```

Answer (score 1):

It is recomended to do it in query rather than in code.

The query could be

```
Select Max(ColName) From TableName;
```

Comment: Oops sorry... I misunderstood that.... but now the question is how to get the number (value) into the code?. empIdLabel.Text = ??????

Answer (score 1):

```
 String cs = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data    
 Source=databasepath\databasename.mdb"; 
 OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(cs);
 con.Open();
 OleDbCommand com = new OleDbCommand("select Max(id) as ID from tablename",
 con);
 com.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
 OleDbDataReader r = com.ExecuteReader();
 r.Read();
 if (r["ID"].ToString() != "")
           {
               temp = int.Parse(r["ID"].ToString()) + 1;
           }
 else
           {
                temp = 1;
           }
 textBox1.Text = temp.ToString();
 r.Close();
 con.Close();
```